# Why I am getting Ambiguous field name 'x' in JOIN

Tags: google-bigquery

> Fact 1 - I am successfully running simple query like below in BigQuery Web UI

```
SELECT
  a.id AS id,
  b.v AS v,
  c.w AS w
FROM (SELECT 1 AS id, "abc" AS x, "xyz" AS y) AS a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT "abc" AS x, "111" AS v) AS b ON a.x = b.x
LEFT JOIN (SELECT "xyz" AS y, "222" AS w) AS c ON a.y = c.y
```

> Fact 2 - When I try to write result [of very same query] to table with below options  - it **fails!**

[image]

> Fact 3 - Same query to table with below options  - **succeeded**!

[image]

> **Question** - Why I am getting this error?

**Note**:
I was asked this question outside of SO, so decided to share here.
As you can see "workaround" is "found" - so please do not suggest how to re-write the query if it is not accompanied with explanation/answer on actual question.

Comment: Did you posted a bug report about this?

Comment: not yet. wanted to wait for potential explanation first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having a similar problem this morning when trying to save a view and found some other people had it when switching between the web UI and batch. From what I gathered, it's a weird corner case you can get with triple joins.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28980157/bigquery-same-query-works-when-submitted-from-ui-and-reports-sql-syntax-error) helpful in figuring out what was going on, specifically this bit:

"The underlying issue here is that the left source of the final JOIN in your query is trying to collapse [a.x] and [b.x] into the same scope, both with the name 'x', and causing this error."

Someone asked a similar question on the [Official Google BigQuery issue and feature tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=459) and got referred to the above SO post.

Hopefully one of those helps clear it up a bit.